# Clearing my JFrame & JPanel in a new game

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I have a simple JPanel for tic-tac-toe, drawing lines...
so class TTT extends JPanel, and holds a GameLogic object inside.

all is good, application is a JFrame in Main adding TTT and all good.

BUT, when i want to restart a new game,
I call "restart" in my TTT which basiclly does  : gameLogic = new GameLogic(); &  repaint();

now my data array is clean and it should paint only lines..

any way Windows is not changed at all.

I've tried everything with no luck.
Any suggestions?

GameBoard.java:

```
public class GameBoard extends javax.swing.JPanel {
private GameBoardLogic GameLogic;

//.....

public void Restart()
{
    GameLogic = new GameBoardLogic();
    removeAll();
    repaint();
}
```

Main.java:

```
public class Main {
private static GameBoard TTT;
private static JFrame application;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    application = new JFrame("Tic-Tac-Tow");
    TTT = new GameBoard();
    application.add(TTT);
    application.setSize(350, 350);
    application.setVisible(true);
    //.....

    if ( JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Do you want to play again?") == 
                                                 JOptionPane.YES_OPTION )
    {
        application.removeAll();
        TTT.Restart();
        application.add(TTT);
        application.validate();
     }
```

Comment: *"Any suggestions??"* 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Fix that sticky '?' key.

Comment: Are you going to post an SSCCE?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This works for me

```
panel.removeAll();
//add your elements
revalidate();
repaint();
```

Comment: @added the code too. Sorry mKorbel, tried it now. didnt work. the windows wouldn't clear. stays with the victory drawings....

Comment: You can try putting revalidate both before and after inserting your elements.